# Regex to see if directory begins with name

Tags: ruby, regex

I was using some code such as the following in my Ruby script:

```
if File.dirname(path) =~ /^www\.example\.com\/foo/
```

And this works great when a file is only one subdirectory deep underneath `/foo`, but unfortunately the condition would fail if the file was underneath say `/foo/bar`. My question is, what can the regex above be modified to so that `File.dirname` will match any file that's underneath at minimum the condition set above and not just one level deep?

Comment: You can try this in place of /foo [\/a-zA-Z]+

Comment: Basically you want to determine if `path` is in or below `/foo`? Not sure you need a regular expression here. You can just compare the beginning of each string, right?

Comment: The problem is files directly underneath `/foo` would match here such as `/foo/somedoc.txt`, however `/foo/bar/somedoc.txt` would not match. As long as it is underneath `/foo/` I want it to evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where I'd eschew a regex entirely:

```
if path.split(File::SEPARATOR)[0,2] == ['www.example.com','foo']
```

More readable, no escaping needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try [File.fnmatch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/File.html#method-c-fnmatch), it uses some matching patterns (similar but not regex), for your case we could use:

```
**foo**
```

Matches all files with path including a directory called foo

```
File.fnmatch('**foo**','foo/test.txt')
#> true
File.fnmatch('**foo**','/boo/foo/test.txt')
#> true
File.fnmatch('**foo**','/boo/test.txt')
#> false
```